# How do I remove the navigation bar from my Android build?

Tags: android, operating-system, beagleboneblack

Since the device I am developing has physical buttons, I do not want to see a navigation bar taking up my screen space. Rowboat-android on Beagleboneblack shows the navigation bar by default. Where do I turn it off?

EDIT: I am not developing applications. I am developing a Beaglebone based device. I want to remove the bar globally from the system. Somewhere there should be a code or setting in the Android source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer at [Building a wireless Android device using BeagleBone Black](http://nelenkov.blogspot.be/2013/07/building-wireless-android-device.html)

Basically I edited `device/ti/beagleboneblack/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` file to set this entry:

```
    <bool name="config_showNavigationBar">false</bool>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IMMERSIVE` flag like this:

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

For more info, I recommend you to take a look at [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).