# Screen Resolution (4DCAPE-43+Beaglebone Black+Android)

Tags: android-4.2-jelly-bean, beagleboneblack

There is a black bar that appears on right hand side of the screen. Below is picture of the issues.

The display is from 4D Systems

[image]

Based on [TI-Android-JB-4.2.2-DevKit-4.1.1 UserGuide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-Android-JB-4.2.2-DevKit-4.1.1_UserGuide#UI_Navigation) the black bar represents a navigation bar. Following is image of the expected image.

[image]

The TI-Android-JB-4.2.2-DevKit-4.1.1 PortingGuide has the following suggestion from section 3.5.2 [Navigation Keys](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-Android-JB-4.2.2-DevKit-4.1.1_PortingGuide#Navigation_Keys)

To activate the Software Navigation Bar, add the following line in overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml. This is done by default for AM335x EVM

```
<bool name="config_showNavigationBar">true</bool>
```

The kernel has been complied with both Boolean values true and false, with the hope that the navigation bar with will be visible as intended or the navigation bar including the black bar is not visible. Either is fine, but not half way.

The following links were referenced in an attempt to resolve this issue.

- [Building a wireless Android device using BeagleBone Black](http://nelenkov.blogspot.be/2013/07/building-wireless-android-device.html)
- [How do I remove the navigation bar from my Android build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286986/how-do-i-remove-the-navigation-bar-from-my-android-build)

**Solution**

Add the following line as suggested in init.am335xevm.rc file.

```
setprop lcd.landscape true
```

The image with navigation keys after applying

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A black bar will appear if the display is in landscape mode and the display resolution is low (not high enough). In order to view the navigation keys add the following lines to init.{ro.hardware|.rc file.

```
# This board has landscape LCD, enable rotation of keys on Navigation bar
setprop lcd.landscape true
```

If the device is rooted try the following using the command to enable or disable the navigation keys

```
adb shell pm disable/enable com.android.systemui
```

Refer to this [link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-Android-JB-4.2.2-DevKit-4.1.1_PortingGuide#Navigation_Keys) for further details.